# Networkx graph varying in size across platforms

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

[image: Mac iPython notebook][image: Windows Pycharm]I have a short code that plots a graph:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15),dpi=300)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
nd = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=node_cols, linewidths=1, node_size=node_sizes)
nd.set_edgecolor('w') #<- set the edgecolor to red on the node markers
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color=edge_cols,width=edge_sizes)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=fs, font_weight='bold')
plt.tick_params(
    axis='both',          # changes apply to both axes
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off', # labels along the bottom edge are off
    left='off',
    labelleft='off')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('foo.pdf')
```

The sizes are different when ran on my Mac in iPython notebook, and when ran on Windows from pycharm. Is there a way to deal with that? How do I knowingly specify edge_sizes and node_sizes?
Thanks!

Comment: can you post pictures of the different sizes please?

Comment: Edited to add images! Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The default figure size and dpi for matplotlib figures in a jupyter notebook is different than in a usual usual script.

You may find out via

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"])
print(plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"])
```

which should print `[6.0, 4.0] 72.0` for a jupyter notebook and `[6.4, 4.8] 100.0` for a script.

In order to set those parameters, either use

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 6,4
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 100
```

to set them for all output,
or

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=100)
```

for the single figure. This way you can ensure to have the same output for both, script and notebook.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to post the part where I initialize the figure and specify size and dpi. I edited the question. I basically do just that, right?

Comment: Yes. It seems so. So one would need to have a [mcve] of the issue.